# how to check if object is null or undefined in angular in ngIF condition

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this inside my code:

```
 <div *ngIf="(listCount$| async) > 0 ">
```

but it won't pass the pipeline because it says

```
Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.
```

in ts file:

```
readonly listCount$ = new BehaviorSubject<number | undefined>(undefined);
```

any help, can i do this in one line?

Comment: Do you represent some specific state of application with undefined? Otherwise you could just initialise it with 0.

Comment: i tried but then i made huge mess and a lot of errors inside other parts of app

Comment: Without changing anything else the only solution would be probably to add second condition ```!!(listCount$| async) && (listCount$| async) > 0``` but this adds second subscription as well.

Comment: Initialize the subject with a number that satisfies the `*ngIf` expression instead of `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an async operation that might result in an undefined value that's why you are getting the error. Provide a default value in case of undefined in your template condition.

```
<div *ngIf="((listCount$| async) ?? 0) > 0 ">
```

OR set the `strictNullChecks` to false in your `tsconfig.json` file.

```
"strictNullChecks": false
```

Demo:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kheete?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Expression expected

Comment: Please check your syntax, I have added stackblitz link as well for reference.

Comment: its not working on my local, maybe its related to the version?

Comment: which version of angular you are using and if you are making changes in tsconfig file then you need to kill and reserve the application again.

Comment: just `*ngIf="listCount$| async"` work for values <>0, <>null, <>undefined and <>false

Comment: @Eliseo If you have enabled strictNullcheck then you will get compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as` syntax for a clean syntax which will allow you to use the listCount as a variable. this variable will evaluate as a condition for a truty/falsy argument so (0, undefined, null, '', NaN) will evaluate as false.

```
<div *ngIf="(listCount$ | async) as listCount;">hello</div>
```

Comment: and where is the condition that listCount needs to be bigger then 0?